# PowerPivot displaying rounded result

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have created a `PowerPivot` Report which contains a `Price` field and a `Sales` as well as a `Measure` column.

`Price` Column will obviously contain the unit price
`Sales` Column will give the units sold
`Measure` Column is the measure of the product.

From this I have a:-
`Total Price` which is `Price`x`Sale` and a
`Total Measure` which is `Measure`x`Sale`

In the calculation section I have then worked out a calc which is Simply

Unit Per Thousand:=`SUM(Products[Total Price])/SUM(Products[Total Measure])*1000`

The issue I am getting is this is rounding it to the nearest 10 So rather than £17.88 it is displaying £17.90. It is set to 2 decimal places already. All the values in the columns are correct to the 2 decimal places. Can anyone assist to get me the correct result and not a rounded result.

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use the round function in DAX on your measure which would allow you to round the result of the calculation.  This being different then setting the field's format settings.

It would be

```
ROUND(<number>, <num_digits>)
```

Link to Microsoft site on the function:
[enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634402.aspx)

Edit:

Then it sounds like you want to use the trunc function in DAX to truncate the number after a certain number of significant digits.

```
TRUNC(<number>,<num_digits>)
```

Comment: This sounds like the opposite of what OP wants. OP is saying they don't want it rounded.

Comment: Exactly yes. I don't want it rounded. I have attempted to the solution and it did not bring the desired result of £17.88 and is still at £17.90

Comment: Unfortunately not working. Unit Per Thousand:=TRUNC(SUM(Products[Total Price])/SUM(Products[Total Measure])*1000,2) is still yielding the same result